# How to Schedule a daily task to run a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a task on Windows Server 2008 to delete some images on a folder. I create a batch file to execute this, my code below:

```
forfiles /s /m *.jpg /D -10 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

(I didn't put the dir because I store the batch file on the same folder where I want to erase the images, so it's no necesary)

My issue is at the time I try to schedule this task to run this automatically. Because when I manually run this file IT ERASE THE IMAGES SUCCESSFULLY, also when I schedule this task with the condition to run it when the administrator is logged in. The problem comes when I specify the condition to run the file either the admin is logged or not and of course with high privileges. I don't know why in this case the task begins running at the time I programmed it, but it never runs the batch file, I can see at the task scheduler that my task is running but nothing's happening. Does somebody have a clue?

I'm including the screenshots of the task scheduler:

[image: This is where I see the task running, as you can see I selected the options for high privileges]

[image: This is the folder where I have my batch file]

[image: Conditions]

[image: Settings]

Comment: I think I'd be scared not to at least use `%~dp0` for tasks deleting things indiscriminately.

Comment: *I didn't put the dir because I store the batch file on the same folder where I want to erase the images, so it's no necesary)* is not always true, especially when using task scheduler.

Comment: But I'm not having troubles with the batch file, because when I run it manually it's executing correctly, and also when I schedule it with the option of administrator logged.

Comment: Is `F:` a local drive or network drive?

Comment: Is a Local drive

Comment: When you check the box to run whether the user is logged on or not, the task will start with the Working Directory being `C:\windows\system32`.  You need to do a change directory at the top of your script or use the `/P` option with `FORFILES`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, this solve my problem. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scheduling tasks to run even if no user is logged on, the working directory becomes `C:\Windows\system32`. So you have to jump to the proper directory or otherwise the files won't be found. Further, you have to use `cd %~dp0` and not `cd %CD%` as `%CD%` will still be the system32 folder whereas `%~dp0` will be the folder your batch file is located in.

EDIT:
Sorry, I've just realized that **Squashman** has already given the same answer as a comment.