# How can I trigger a Python code automatically?

Tags: python, oracle, optimization, triggers

I have a code in Oracle which is optimized and create weekly data. The problem is I also want my Oracle code trigger Python to run and create data in Python and save. Is there any possibility to execute my Python code automatically?

Comment: If you're on linux `cron` job would be good.

Comment: no, I'm not :( do you know any solution to handle it in Windows

Comment: On windows the Task scheduler can be used in order to rerun tasks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085250/how-to-schedule-a-daily-task-to-run-a-batch-file

Comment: *"trigger Python to run and create data in Python and save"*. When will the python code run? Where will the python code save the data it creates?

Comment: i want my data to be created when my automatic oracle code ended. so after that python will have execution point which it will start running and save the data as excel.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger python script by setting up a cron job.

You can do this using python and crontab: see this documentation https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/

Comment: will it help in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

you can use crons jon, task schedule to run the script in particular time. If you want to run the script as service you can use celery and crontab module.

Comment: does it help me to run my code without running it? my main point is to execute my Oracle code to run python automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to leave Python running, and let a Continuous Query Notification (CQN) callback from the data change invoke a python method.  Or use Oracle Advanced Queues for the same.  Examples are in https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples

You could also use the DB's UTL_HTTP functionality to invoke a web service that runs python.

Answer (score 0):

i use windows task planner with a .bat script to run my python code everyday.